# Customizing textarea scrollbar and resizer

Tags: html, css, styles, textarea

I'm trying to stylize the scrollbar of the textarea element. And the problem is if I add text in the textarea field the size of the resizer looks pretty small (see the screenshot)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFUXh.png)

An example with style for the textarea:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

How can I stylizing the scrollbar without any affects to the resizer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner{
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works, but when you hover over the scrollbar, the width of the scrollbar increases

Comment: @Rail could you maybe provide a screenshot of what you're seeing, because everything works fine for me but maybe I understood it wrong